# How to end Razor helper output right after the trailing HTML tag?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a Razor helper like this:

```
@helper MyHelper(string text)
{
    <a href="...">@text</a>
}
```

This outputs a space after it. I can avoid it by adding ";" behind the HTML like this:

```
<a href="...">@text</a>;
```

but then ReSharper complains about an empty statement. Not that it would be that important but maybe there's a cleaner way to do this? The semicolon looks more like a "hack" to me, not a proper solution.

Comment: try `@Html.Raw(text)` ;but be advised I dont have much razer experience.

Comment: That takes away all the syntax highlighting. I'd generally like to use Razor syntax inside my helper, not a plain string.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods I found so far:

1) Put a semicolon at the end of the line, like:

```
@helper MyHelper(string text)
{
    <a href="...">@text</a>;
}
```

2) Put a server-side comment after the HTML tag, like this:

```
@helper MyHelper(string text)
{
    <a href="...">@text</a>@**@
}
```